# CSS mobile background img moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code should stretch and fix background image, it stretches image and fixes but when I scroll on mobile, background img moves up and down on parts of img. It stays in full(no white parts of page) screen but it goes up and down. Here is the code, I have day/night imgs so I use JS in HTML.

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

if(n >= 6 && n <= 20){
$('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_day.jpg" alt=""></div>');
}
else{
$('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_night.jpg" alt=""></div>');
}
</script>
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE(use mobile):** [testing.webatu.com](http://testing.webatu.com/)

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bS53X/)

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/bS53X/

Comment: live for mobile testing.webatu.com , here you can see that how img moves